# how to create one table which is composed of two tables

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have two table, and I want to mix them forever *(something like `join`, but not temporarily, forever in the database)*.

**My tables:**

```
// table1 
+------+----------+-----------+
|  id  |   name   |   color   |
+------+----------+-----------+
|  1   |   peter  |           |
|  2   |   jack   |           |
|  3   |   ali    |           |
+------+----------+-----------+

// table2
+------+----------+
|  id  |   color  |
+------+----------+
|  1   |   pink   |
|  2   |   blue   |
|  3   |   red    |
+------+----------+
```

Now, I want to create a new table which is composed of two tables. something like this:

```
// main_table 
+------+----------+-----------+
|  id  |   name   |   color   |
+------+----------+-----------+
|  1   |   peter  |   pink    |
|  2   |   jack   |   blue    |
|  3   |   ali    |   red     |
+------+----------+-----------+
```

I can do it with `join`:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t2.color from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id
```

So, Is it possible to I do it with a sql query in phpmyadmin and create a new table of it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `create table as`:

```
create table newtable as
    select t1.id, t1.name, t2.color
    from table1 t1 inner join
         table2 t2
         on t1.id = t2.id;
```

However, a view might be sufficient:

```
create view v_table as
    select t1.id, t1.name, t2.color
    from table1 t1 inner join
         table2 t2
         on t1.id = t2.id;
```

Comment: Thanks, I wanted the same thing. just what is difference between `create table` and `create view` ?

Comment: @stack . . . `create table` creates a table (copies the data).  `create view` just puts the logic in the database, so the join needs to be repeated each time a query uses the view.